# check a Date in a range of value except beginner value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to check a time that is between a range of Date. i write this code:

```
  const twoDayLater = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  const OneDayLater = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  const runOfOutUsers = await SubscriptionExtention.find({ expireTime: { $gt: OneDayLater, $lte: twoDayLater } })
```

but I dont want to accept documents that expireTime field of this is equal to OneDayLater. in mathematical words i want to check expiretime = (OneDayLater, twoDayLater]. how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$gt` and `$lte` work on a millisecond level, it won't affect the day

Also if you are referring to a day granularity, `(OneDayLater, twoDayLater]` mean all subscription from `twoDayLater` only. And to set that:

```
const twoDayLater = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

const startOfDay = new Date(twoDayLater).setHours(0,0,0,0); 
const endOfDay = new Date(twoDayLater).setHours(23,59,59,999);

const runOfOutUsers = await SubscriptionExtention.find({ expireTime: { $gte: startOfDay, $lte: endOfDay } })
```